# Swift SpriteKit iAd in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, layout, sprite-kit, iad

I have a Spritekit game and i am able to display iAds. My problem is that when i turn phone in landscape mode, iAd banner doesn't stretch to reach screen bounds width. Here is the code:

```
   import SpriteKit
   import UIKit
 import iAd

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var adBannerView:ADBannerView = ADBannerView()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
       loadAds()
       self.adBannerView.hidden = true
       ....



 func loadAds()->ADBannerView{
            //adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zero)


    adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: view!.frame.size.width / 2, y: view!.frame.size.height - 550) 
    adBannerView.delegate = self

    self.view?.addSubview(adBannerView)



    return adBannerView



   }
     func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
   // banner.alpha = 0.0
    //self.adBannerView.alpha = 0.0
    print("Ad cannot load")
    banner.alpha = 0.0
    self.adBannerView.alpha = 0.0
    self.adBannerView.hidden = true
    //banner.alpha = 0.0
    //self.adBannerView.alpha = 0.0
}
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    print("ad did load.")
    self.adBannerView.hidden = false
}
```

Why in landscape mode my iAd banner doesn't stretch automatically to reach screen size width?

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the `didChangeSize` method of your scene:

```
override func didChangeSize(oldSize: CGSize) {
    super.didChangeSize(oldSize)
    // your resizing code here
}
```

You'll need to override another method in your `GameViewController` as well:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    if let scene = skView.scene {

        let scene = scene as! GameScene
        if scene.size != self.view.bounds.size {
            scene.size = self.view.bounds.size
        }
    }
}
```

When the device rotates, the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method is called, which is where you'll want to resize the scene and call your game logic.

Comment: Doesn't work...viewDidLayoutSubviews() gives me that error: Could not cast value of type 'mygame.MainMenuScene' (0x10d0f8) to 'mygame.GameScene' (0x10ce78). Can you help me?

Comment: Since you're just changing the scene size, you can go ahead and remove the 'as! GameScene'.

Answer (score 1):

I have a helper on GitHub you can check out. https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-iAds-AdMob-CustomAds-Helper

Essentially what I do is change my ads in this method in the viewController

```
   override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in



       let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
      switch orientation {
       case .Portrait:
         print("Portrait")
          // Do something
       default:
         print("Anything But Portrait")
           // Do something else
       }

        }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
            print("Device rotation completed")
    })
}
```

This gets called on screen rotation and I use it to update my ads size.

Is this helping?

Comment: Seems interesting...the problem is that my project doesn't have any viewController...only a GameViewController, a MainMenuScene and a GameScene...How can i try to fit your example to my project?

Comment: The gameView controller is a UIviewController

Comment: Your idea give me the chance to implement a totally new simple method. I just removed all my previous code and simply added this line in viewDidLoad in GameViewController: canDisplayBannerAds = true.  Ads are now showing correctly in portrait and in Landscape mode. The only little problem is that i can't change banner position...but i changed some elements of my scene to coexist with my new banner...

Comment: Yeah the problem with this method is that it is resizes your view, as in its moving the screen up. Probably not ideal for game. Up to you

Comment: yes...i tried with your method, but if i put a code inside, for example, case . default: my scene in landscape mode resizes to half

Comment: If you make a game in SpriteKit you shouldn't support both orientations anyway.

Comment: Dont think so, its a new ios 8 method. As I asked before why are you trying to make a spriteKit game in both orientations?

Comment: Only to have one more opportunity for my game...but after this conversation i'm seriously thinking of changing my original guidelines. Peraphs i'll make my game only in portrait mode, it's more functional and so i can focus more on gameplay

Comment: Rotation doesnt really  give your game more opportunity at all. In the contrary it probably makes it much worse. Its is nearly impossible to make it work both ways, its a nightmare. I mean maybe a quiz game or something super basic but any kind of regular game no way

Comment: Thank you for the advice...i'll do it in portrait mode

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

i tried with this code from [Display an iAd banner in landscape in swift & spritekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252539/display-an-iad-banner-in-landscape-in-swift-spritekit?rq=1)

```
let screenBounds: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    var adBannerView: ADBannerView  
    adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, screenBounds.width))
    adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: screenBounds.width/2, y: screenBounds.height-adBannerView.frame.height)
    adBannerView.delegate = self
    adBannerView.hidden = true
    view.addSubview(adBannerView)
```

iAd works perfectly in landscape mode in simulator, but give the same issue on my iphone...why?